# Configure Spring Security with Jersey REST and Swagger UI

Tags: java, spring-security, jersey, spring-boot, swagger

I have a Java Spring Boot Jersey (REST) application in which I want to add Spring Security (for LDAP in my case). Also, I'm using Swagger UI.

In my `application.yml` file I think I need to have `spring.jersey.type: filter` to serve static Swagger files.
However, the security doesn't seem to protect the jersey endpoints anymore with that setting.
It (security) does however protect swagger files.

My controller:

```
@Component
@Path("/report")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ReportController {
    @GET
    public String getReport(){
        // stuff...
```

My jersey config:

```
@Component
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyConfig() {
        packages(true, "package.resources");
        property(ServletProperties.FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404, true);
    }
}
```

Security config

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Resource
    private LdapConfiguration ldapConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").hasRole(ldapConfiguration.getValidationRole())
                .and()
            .formLogin();
    }

    @Configuration
    protected static class AuthenticationConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

        @Resource
        private LdapConfiguration ldapConfiguration;

        private LdapContextSource getLdapContext() throws Exception {
            LdapContextSource context = new LdapContextSource();
            context.setUrl(ldapConfiguration.getUrl());
            context.setBase(ldapConfiguration.getBase());
            context.setUserDn(ldapConfiguration.getUserDn());
            context.setPassword(ldapConfiguration.getPassword());
            context.afterPropertiesSet();
            return context;
        }

        @Override
        public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth
                .ldapAuthentication()
                .userSearchFilter(ldapConfiguration.getUserSearchFilter())
                .userSearchBase(ldapConfiguration.getUserSearchBase())
                .groupSearchBase(ldapConfiguration.getGroupSearchBase())
                .groupRoleAttribute(ldapConfiguration.getGroupRoleAttribute())
                .groupSearchFilter(ldapConfiguration.getGroupSearchFilter())
                .contextSource(getLdapContext());
        }
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
server:
  context-path: /myapi
  port: 9091
spring:
  jersey.type: filter
```

Comment: `@ApplicationPath()` can be used it seems